# Cardinality of a set of random variables (measurable functions): $|L_0|=|L_p|=|L_\infty|$ for any $p >0$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory, statistics, elementary-set-theory

How can we compare the cardinalities of   different sets of random variables on a given probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$.

Is $|L_1|>|L_\infty|$, while $L_\infty$ is dense in $L_1$?

When does the following  $$|L_p|=|L_\infty|$$ hold for all  $p\ge1$?

How large can be the set $L_0$  of all random variables compared to $L_\infty$?

How much are we lucky if a given distribution has a finite mean or finite variance?

How restrictive is if a statement only holds for random variables with mgf?

How are these cardinalities connected to the cardinality of $\Omega$,

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Lp_spaces_and_Lebesgue_integrals) for definition of $L_p$ spaces. Here, $L_0$ denotes the set of all random variables (Borel measurable functions) defined on the probability space.

Specifically interested in two cases of  $(\Omega, 2^\Omega)$ where $\Omega$ is a finite set and $(\mathbb R, \mathcal B(\mathbb R)).$
For the latter, from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/369859/1231520), we know that $$|L_0|=|\mathbb R|,$$

whereas the cardinality of the set of all Lebesgue measurable functions is $|2^\mathbb R|$ (which shows how small is the set of random variables, but note that they have the same cardinality of  $|\mathbb R|$ considering equivalence classes). From the above, I think we have $$|L_{\frac{1}{p}}|=|L_p|=|\mathbb R|$$ for all  $p\ge1$ as $$|\mathbb R|=|L_0|\ge|L_{\frac{1}{p}}|\ge|L_p|\ge|L_\infty|\ge|\mathbb R|.$$ On the other hand, when $\Omega$ is finite, we have

$$|L_0|=|L_p|=|L_{\frac{1}{p}}|=|L_\infty|$$

for any $p\ge1$.

Can we **generalize** these two observations as follows?

> 1- For any given $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$, we always have $$|L_0|=|L_{\frac{1}{p}}|=|L_p|=|L_\infty|$$ for any $p\ge 1$.

If **yes**, then

> 2- How can we define **a bijection** (one-to-one correspondence) for each pair of these spaces?

In question 1, I also guess considering equivalence classes does not change the result.

---

PS: Related Stack Exchange questions on sets with $|\mathbb R|$ cardinality:

[Cardinality of set of real continuous functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/477/13130)

[Cardinality of the borel measurable functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/369859/13130)

[Cardinality of the set of entire functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4192615/1231520)

[Cardinality of the set of Lebesgue measurable functions under equivalence](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1916711/1231520)

The cardinality of the Riemann integrable functions is $|2^\mathbb R|.$

[Cardinality of the set of Riemann integrable functions on [0,1]](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2793393/13130)

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152194/discussion-on-question-by-amir-cardinality-of-a-set-of-random-variables-measura); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Fix $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ as a probability space. A random variable is a Borel measurable function $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Define:

\begin{align*}
U &= \{\mbox{Random variables $X:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$}\}\\
B &= \{\mbox{Random variables $X:\Omega\rightarrow (-\pi/2, \pi/2)$} \}
\end{align*}

Claim: $|B|=|U|$.

Proof: Note that if $X \in U$ then $\arctan(X)$ is a random variable (since it is a continuous function of $X$) and $\arctan(X) \in B$. Define the function $f:U\rightarrow B$ given by
$$ f(X) = \arctan(X) \quad \forall X \in U$$
This function $f$ is surjective because if $Y\in B$ then $\tan(Y) \in U$ and $f(\tan(Y))=Y$. This function $f$ is injective since if $X_1, X_2$ are two random variables in $U$ that satisfy $f(X_1)=f(X_2)$, then $\arctan(X_1)=\arctan(X_2)$ and so $X_1=X_2$.
Thus, $f$ is a bijection between $U$ and $B$. $\Box$

---

- In the special case when $\mathcal{F}=Pow(\Omega)$ then all functions $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ are random variables and $|U|=|\mathbb{R}^{\Omega}|$.
- In the special case when $\Omega$ is finite or countably infinite and $\mathcal{F}=Pow(\Omega)$ then $|U|=|\mathbb{R}|$, since
  $$ |\mathbb{R}|\leq |\mathbb{R}^{\Omega}|\leq |\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}|=|\mathbb{R}|$$

Comment: Note that $B$ is a subset of all random variables that are bounded, also a subset of all random variables that are almost surely bounded, also a subset of all random variables $X$ such that $E[|X|^p]<\infty$ for some $p>0$. So the cardinalities of all of these is at least $|B|$ and at most $|U|$, and since $|B|=|U|$ we are done.